# Check probability

Tags: c++, unit-testing, boost

I have a C++ application which based on some algorithm chooses one of 5 entities for some actions.

I am writing a unit test to make sure that all 5 has the same probability to be chosen. I am running test for 1000 times and getting results how many times each of them had been chosen. Here is the result example
202, 192, 224, 195, 187

How it would be right to add check if the count is close to 200?

I am using boost test library.

Comment: Set a boundary for what you consider to be "close to 200". Subtract 200 from the result, get the absolute value and see if it's in the boundary.

Comment: @DeiDei So let's say 10% then 200 - 20 < n < 200 + 20 ?

Comment: A more general solution would be to actually measure the variance: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance

Comment: You'll have to pick a threshold for the allowable variance. Though, this threshold will yield a confidence interval which means that once in a while a properly randomized sample will eventually exceed that threshold. There is no perfect solution for validating exactly a distribution from samples due to the nature of randomness.

Comment: How about subtracting the mean (200), taking the absolute value, and testing if it's less then 10%*200=20?

Comment: This is a statistics question rather than a programming question. Consider asking at math.stackexchange.com instead.

Comment: If there is some probability of a result occurring that is not equal to 1, there is also a non-zero probability it does NOT occur.  Any unit test you devise will therefore sometimes fail even if the algorithm behaves as required.  Rather than using a unit test of the distribution, you would be better off conducting analysis to determine the set of input conditions that cause the algorithm to exhibit required statistical behaviour, and confirm that the algorithm is only provided such inputs. Unit tests might then be an option to confirm the algorithm is always provided with suitable inputs.

Answer (score 0):

A quick rule of thumb is that in a sample of X of Y%, you'll usually get Y%*X +/- sqrt(X).

That is an approximation of the 2nd standard deviation, so the odds you are within +/- sqrt(X) elements is roughly 95%.

You can use 1.5*sqrt(X) for an approximation of 3 standard deviations, which should happen 99.7% of the time.

You could also back up and use fancy statistics to get a more precice answer.

So on 1000 samples, that is +/- 31 for sqrt(X), or +/- 47 for 1.6*sqrt(X).

This sqrt rule generates a bound that is looser than it needs to be.

To derive it, start with the fact that a Y chance coin has a Var of (1-Y)(Y).  Note that this polynomial is maximal at Y=0.5.

So Var(X coins with prob Y) <= X Var(Y) = X/4.

SD(X coins with prob Y) is then <= sqrt(X/4) = sqrt(X)/2.

95% interval is 1.96 SD; 2 is greater than that.  So 1.96 SD <= sqrt(X).

A proper derivation would take into account that we want students T distribution as we are estimating Y from a sample from X*Y, and not estimating X*Y from Y, but given the generous fudge factors.

Looking at the [chart on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/68%E2%80%9395%E2%80%9399.7_rule), if you do a test 1/day you can expect a failure:

- 1 sigma: 2x/week
- 2 sigma: every 3 weeks
- 3 sigma: every year
- 4 sigma: every 43 years (twice a lifetime)
- 5 sigma: every 4776 years (once in recorded history)
- 6 sigma: every million  years (once in human species lifetime)

As sqrt(X) is an approximation of 2 sigma, 2*sqrt(X) will get you 2 spurious unit test failures per lifetime, and 3*sqrt(X) should never in practice fail.

Note that if you are repeating this test a million times per day you may need more sigma.

Comment: Since this question is in the context of a unit test, a 95% confidence means that the unit test will still fail 5% of the time even if the code generating it contains no error. The problem is compounded if you have to test multiple distributions. Unit tests don't seem to me like the right place to check the correctness of a distribution.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Boost the sigma, and it reaches the point where spurious failures are less likely than cosmic rays flipping the bit that states the failure happened.

Comment: As mentioned above, I would add unit tests for other methods that implement the distribution which are deterministic. Consider adding the test for the probability as an integration test instead of unit test.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont If you do that enough, your test will pass even if your distribution is bad.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to achieve is "validation": You want to check if the system you have implemented fits your needs.  Which, in your case, means that you want to check if the algorithm delivers the data with the proper distribution.

Or, looking at the same thing from a different angle: You are not checking if you have made some bug when doing the implementation - even if your code is bug free it might simply not do what you want.

This is not the kind of tests that unit-testing is for.  Unit-testing is for "verification" and aims at finding bugs in the code - it is not for figuring out if your choice of algorithm is proper.  To give an analogy: With unit-testing you could check if you have implemented quick-sort properly, but it is not for checking if you should rather have implemented heap-sort.

This is not meant to say that your testing objective does not make sense - it is only to explain that the tests you are implementing are not unit-test in the usual sense.  Moreover, your tests lack one important property that unit-tests normally should have: being deterministic.

That said, you still can implement your tests with one of the so-called unit-testing frameworks, because these frameworks are in no way limited to doing unit-testing with them.  I simply would recommend not to implement and run these tests with your unit-tests.  It also does not really make sense to run them at the same frequency: Once you know that you have chosen the algorithm properly, you can write some (real) unit-tests to find bugs / regressions.  These unit-tests you would run regularly, but the validation tests don't have to be re-run.